# Cloudsearch Prefix query ignoring words after a spac

Tags: amazon-web-services, search, filtering, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm trying to write a query that works similar to autocomplete. 
I cannot use a suggester as I also need to add a filter query.
I'm using the below query but it's not ignoring words preceded by a space.

```
q=(and ( prefix 'lond' ) (not (prefix ' lond') ) )
```

E.g. This returns
City of London where it should only return London

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the way Amazon tokenizes Strings, splitting on space in paticular.
To work around this, I have created a new index field called `autocomplete_name` where I simply join the String with underscores.

So `City Of London` becomes `City_Of_London` which is perfect for autocomplete.